# Prove that an argument is invalid using inference rules

Tags: logic

I have the following argument

Premises

(1) $ p \iff q $

(2) $ p \implies \neg r $

Conclusion
$ q \veebar r $

Where $\veebar$ Is the exclusive disjunction.

By using the truth tables I've found that the argument is invalid since $((p \iff q) \land (p \implies \neg r)) \implies (q \veebar r)$ is not a tautology.

But I have to prove that it is invalid using the inference rules.

I tried to use inference rules on (1) and (2) to obtain the negation of conclusion but without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot prove that is "invalid" with inference rules: you have to use a counter-example (a line in the TT that outputs False).

Comment: OK. Two questions. (1) Is It a general rule or does it depend on the particular form of the argument? (2) And if I take the negation of conclusion and add it to premises? Can I do something in this way?

Comment: No.  $(p\leftrightarrow q)\land(\lnot p\to r)\land\lnot(q\veebar r)$ is not a contradiction.